# mysql select statement is not working

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I don't seem to be able to get my SELECT statement to work.

**This is the table:**

```
CREATE TABLE clients(
    user_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    email VARCHAR (70) NOT NULL,
    mobile_number int(11) NOT NULL, 
    UNIQUE KEY (email) 
);
```

**The Select Query**

```
SELECT user_id FROM clients WHERE email='info@candy.co.uk';
```

Whenever I try using this SELECT statement from mysqlADMIN it returns `null`; this happens even when I enter an email address that I know is in the database.

I would really appreciate some advice on where I am going wrong.

Comment: You might have empty spaces in that string,try to TRIM the column.

Comment: What do you mean by "*it returns null*"?  Is it returning one (or more) records with a null value, or is it returning no records?

Comment: Have you tried selecting everything `*` to see what you get back?

Comment: hello. sorry. its returning no records

Comment: Hello Mihai. how do you trim the column? i suspect that you might be onto somthing?

Comment: Hello, When I tried this SQL statement from sql it says  "Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key". its because your unique key should be auto increament

Comment: That query seems to be working fine. See this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27f99/1)

Answer (score 3):

Try the statement without the "WHERE" clause. If it returns the entire table you have narrowed it down to an error in your "email" string.

If it returns nothing and you know there is data in this table then check your connection string and make sure you are using the correct DB.

Comment: While helpful, this does not attempt to answer the question. It provides a method of troubleshooting, but no specific answer.

Comment: Hello smidy. i tried your suggestion and it did indeed return the entire table. this means that there is a problem in the email string. however, when i also tried the same SELECT query to check for an idential mobile number it also return 'no records found'. so, must be a serious problem somewhere

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some error in your SQL create statement. You should make the unique key to which you have applied auto increment. In this case the database will give an error.

Please try the following creation statement

```
CREATE TABLE clients(
user_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
email VARCHAR (70) NOT NULL,
mobile_number int(11) NOT NULL
);
```